# Time limit exceeded in GeeksForGeeks zig zig traversal in tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, traversal

I am working on the GeeksForGeeks [ZigZag Tree Traversal](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/zigzag-tree-traversal/1#) problem:

> Given a Binary Tree. Find the Zig-Zag Level Order Traversal of the Binary Tree.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
>     3
>   /   \
>  2     1
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> 3 1 2
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
>           7
>        /     \
>       9       7
>     /  \     /   
>    8    8   6     
>   /  \
>  10   9
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> 7 7 9 8 8 6 9 10
> ```

I am getting a Time Limit Exceeded error.

My approach is to push a `NULL` for each different level, and at every `NULL` I am changing the direction:

```
vector<int> ans;
queue<Node*> q;
q.push(root);
q.push(NULL);
int k = 1;

while (q.size() > 0)
{
    Node * top = q.front();
    q.pop();
    if (!top)
    {
        k = 1 - k;
        q.push(NULL);
        continue;
    }
    ans.push_back(top->data);
    if (k)
    {
        if (top->right)
            q.push(top->right);
        if (top->left)
            q.push(top->left);
    }
    else
    {
        if (top->left)
            q.push(top->left);
        if (top->right)
            q.push(top->right);
    }   
}
```

Why is this code not finishing in time?

Comment: *it showing TLE pls help* -- Please do not use abbreviations such as "TLE".  Contrary to popular belief, most C++ programmers do not know what you mean by "TLE".  Second, that site you linked to has very poor C++ examples -- if you're using that site to learn C++, you won't learn it properly.

Comment: Your question should include the description of the code challenge. Link can be useful, but essential information must be embedded in the question.

Comment: As there is no reaction, I have updated the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that causes the time out is related to the `NULL` you keep on the queue. That means the queue will never get empty. If you pop a `NULL` and the queue becomes empty, you still push a new `NULL` unto it so your loop never ends.

You could fix this by changing the while condition to `q.size()>1`, but then still there is a flaw in the algorithm:

When visiting the nodes in a level from left to right, you correctly put the right child first in the queue, and then the left child, but this only reverses the direct children. The cousins are still relating to eachother in the left-to-right order, which is wrong.

I would suggest to use two vectors instead of one queue, and let those vectors alternate.

Here is how your code would need to be adapted:

```
    vector <int> zigZagTraversal(Node* root)
    {
        vector<int> ans;
        vector<Node*> parents;
        vector<Node*> children;
        children.push_back(root);
        int k = 0;

        while (children.size() > 0)
        {
            k = 1 - k;
            parents = children;
            children.clear();
            while (parents.size() > 0)
            {
                Node * top = parents.back();
                parents.pop_back();
                ans.push_back(top->data);
                if (top->right && k == 0)
                    children.push_back(top->right);
                if (top->left)
                    children.push_back(top->left);
                if (top->right && k == 1)
                    children.push_back(top->right);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@trincot

thankyou for your help

I got it where I am making mistake.

I should check the size of queue before pushing NULL
Because,  at time of last NULL (what the code is doing poping NULL , check it ooh it is NULL then again push a NULL and continue doing it)

so, I have to check the size of queue  at the time of pushing NULL if it is zero
have to break the loop